# Is it normal to cache data in JavaScript from Java application server by exploiting 304 HTTP respond

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, http, caching

My application extensively use hierarchical data selections (taxonomy selects), like (but not exactly):

```
Country
  => State
    => City
      => Street
```

So user select first level option, JS AJAX load second level, after user selection AJAX load third level, and so on...

I think that one way to speedup application is to load whole hierarchy as JS file and directly use this data from JavaScript exploiting **If-Modified-Since**/**Last-Modified** and **304** respond code for caching this large (50 KiB, 12 after `gzip`) and time consuming (300 ms for getting from DB) data.

I don't jet implement such technique as afraid that to invent wheel. In case if I try to implement I would use below technique...

Spring now support [Last-Modified](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-lastmodified) HTTP 1.1 header:

```
@RequestMapping
public String myHandleMethod(WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    long lastModified = // 1. application-specific calculation
    if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
        // 2. shortcut exit - no further processing necessary
        return null;
     }
    // 3. or otherwise further request processing, actually preparing content
    model.addAttribute(...);
    return "myViewName";
}
```

Oracle allow fast checks for tables changes by [ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS/USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2097.htm):

```
select timestamps from all_tab_modifications where table_name = 'COUNTRY';
select timestamps from all_tab_modifications where table_name = 'STATE';
...
```

On JSP pages which use hierarchical data I include js file:

```
 <script src="<c:url value='js/db/units.js'/>"></script>
```

with full hierarchy data in form (like this do [Java DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)):

```
uniqPrefix.units = {
  "USA": {
      "Alabama": { 
          "Montgomery": ["Street 1", "Street 2"],
          "Birmingham": ["Street 3", "Street 4"],
      }, ...
   "UK": { ... }
}
```

so HTML `<select>` tags filled by JavaScript code from `js/db/units.js` without any Ajax queries...

And on server side we don't regenerate `js/db/units.js` if `Country`, `State`, `City`, `Street` tables isn't modified from last time user visit our site...

Is it normal to cache data in JavaScript from application server by exploiting browser **If-Modified-Since** request parameter and **304** HTTP server respond or this is broken approach at all?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about a Javascript-driven HTTP client compared to any other HTTP client, and what you're describing is exactly what 304 responses are designed for. Your application *should* avoid re-loading data if it has not changed.

Comment: Thanks for answer! +1. One thing that I get for free (without any extra lines of code) with such technique is automatic **parsing/caching** of included JS file into rendered .html page. Because I *directly* include JS and hide data behind *namespace*... So it is not just caching...

Comment: Or to put it another way, it's not just caching the result of an HTTP call -- it is also caching the result of parsing/processing. Which is all good.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite normal to use caching to avoid re-retrieving JS from the server - whether it is a good idea in your case depends on how the page will be used. If you expect a typical user to make multiple selections from the heirarchy (which would otherwise need multiple AJAX calls) then caching sounds like a good idea.

From a performance perspective it is also usually far better to make one big call than lots of small ones, each separate call to the server has an overhead associated with it - by caching all the JS as you describe you only pay this penalty once.